# File permission issues in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

PFA the png, in this please note the permissions for the images inside app_themes directory. I am creating and adding files to this directory(app_themes) and during the process I do not specify any permissions at all.

[image: Scrrenshot of app_themes directory]

Now I can see, for some png's the permission is rwxrwxrwx and for some others, it is just rw.

Though I do not specify any permission at all, why this difference in permission occurs?

I have no issues while I access a file with rwxrwxrwx from a different application, but cannot access those files which has only rw permission from a second application.

Please let me know how to resolve this by having the same permission - rwxrwxrwx for all the files.

This behaviour of android seems slightly strange!

Any help is much appreciated.

In first place, why android sets different permissions for different files, though the files are created using the same code?

Comment: `File directory = cw.getDir(THEME_DIR, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
File mypath = new File(directory, filename + ".png");
 FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to
            // the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`